# Paragraph transfer from one file to another

Tags: cut-copy-paste, gvim

Which commands can you use to take a paragraph from one file and insert it in a second file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can jump around paragraphs with `{` `}`. Yank a paragraph with `y}`, if you are positioned above the paragraph you want. Then you use `:e file2` to open the other file (or whichever method you use to switch between open files). Then `p` for paste to paste the paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

You could get a better answer if you'd provided more information. Nonetheless:

- `dap` will delete (`d`) around (`a`) the current paragraph (`p`).
- move to the next buffer (file). E.g. with `:bNext`.
- go to where you wanna paste the paragraph. E.g. `21G`.
- paste it with `p`.

Just provide more information if it is not your usercase. (:

Comment: thank you for your time assisting me!  I'm quite new to this; how can I copy one paragraph from current file without deleting it, and past the same paragraph into another file please?  Thank You!

Comment: You're welcome. Since you said '_to take a paragraph from one file and insert_' I thought you wanted to 'cut it'. If you want just to copy it, substitute `dap` for `yap`. If you confirm that it works, I'll be glad to update the answer. (:

Comment: Great. But please, take a look at the moderators note. If possible @Man, update your question explaining what exactely is your problem and situation, then the answer will be updated to answer your problem and also explain the Vim's concepts behing it.